# Show dialog window

Tags: python, dialog, pyqt4

Can anyone tell me why this code is not working? The `Test4` class is my converted simple UI:

```
import sys
import Test4
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class UiViewer(QtGui.QApplication, Test4.Ui_Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        return super(UiViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def main(self):
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    uiViewer = UiViewer()
    uiViewer.main()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: What are your errors? Do you have a traceback to post?

Answer (score 0):

first of all 
you need to use

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
```

not

```
if name == 'main':
```

and also adding the Error Message and describing the behavior of the application when you run it will help trace the problem. 
from your question, it can be any number of problems.

Comment: The apparent `__name__ == '__main__'` issue was just caused by wrong formatting of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `UiViewer` class needs to inherit from the same class as the top-level widget in Qt Designer (presumably `QDialog`, in your case, but it could also be a `QMainWindow` or a `QWidget`):

```
class UiViewer(QtGui.QDialog, Test4.Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UiViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

And note that you must not put `return` before the `super` call, otherwise the `__init__` function will exit at that point, meaning the rest of its code won't be executed (in particular, `setupUi` would not be called).

Comment: Thanks to you...  up and running